# os.walk very slow, any way to optimise?

Tags: python, optimization, os.walk

I am using `os.walk` to build a map of a data-store (this map is used later in the tool I am building)

This is the code I currently use:

```
def find_children(tickstore):
    children = []
    dir_list = os.walk(tickstore)
    for i in dir_list:
        children.append(i[0])
    return children
```

I have done some analysis on it:

`dir_list = os.walk(tickstore)` runs instantly, if I do nothing with `dir_list` then this function completes instantly.

It is iterating over `dir_list` that takes a long time, even if I don't `append` anything, just iterating over it is what takes the time.

`Tickstore` is a big datastore, with ~10,000 directories.

Currently it takes approx 35minutes to complete this function.

Is there any way to speed it up?

I've looked at alternatives to `os.walk` but none of them seemed to provide much of an advantage in terms of speed.

Comment: `return [dir for dir, _, _ in os.walk(tickstore)]` might be a bit more efficient, but hard drive access is relatively slow in general.

Comment: What do you do with the generated list of children? Maybe you don't even need the entire list since the next thing you do is to filter/scan the sequence for things?

Comment: I'd assume even slower as it is accessing a network drive?

Comment: Accessing a network drive has some more overhead.

Comment: Next step is to find valid files within that list on directories, yes. But to filter them out at this earlier stage would still require iteration and it is the iteration that's taking the time.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @JoeSmart if you're looking for valid *files*, why are you only looking at the *directories* from `os.walk`? Are you then going back to get the files for each directory (which you've just thrown away)? This is starting to seem a lot like an XY problem...

Comment: `dir_list` is a [**generator**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/), not a `list` (c: So, it'll only access the drive when iterated over.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the `os.walk` creates a list of directories in which files can be stored. The structure of this datastore also allows me to filter, so the whole directory name is needed. The next function I call on children uses the directories along with `os.listdir` to filter out invalid files within those directories.

Comment: @JoeSmart: `os.walk()` gets your the file list already. Don't discard the info, use it.

Comment: @JoeSmart I strongly suggest that you **read the documentation** for the function you're using. Each iteration of `os.walk` returns three things: the directory you're currently in; a list of the sub-directories in that directory; and a list of the files in that directory. It is also a generator, so can be used more efficiently if you don't need everything at once. It seems certain that there is a smarter way to do what you're currently doing that will give both performance and readability/maintainability benefits.

Answer (score 12):

Yes: use Python 3.5 (which is still currently a RC, but [should be out momentarily](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0478/)). In Python 3.5, `os.walk` was rewritten to be more efficient.

This work done as part of [PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471).

Extracted from the PEP:

> Python's built-in `os.walk()` is significantly slower than it needs to
>   be, because -- in addition to calling `os.listdir()` on each directory
>   -- it executes the `stat()` system call or `GetFileAttributes()` on each file to determine whether the entry is a directory or not.
>
> But the underlying system calls -- `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` on
>   Windows and `readdir` on POSIX systems -- already tell you whether the
>   files returned are directories or not, so no further system calls are
>   needed. Further, the Windows system calls return all the information
>   for a `stat_result` object on the directory entry, such as file size and
>   last modification time.
>
> In short, you can reduce the number of system calls required for a
>   tree function like `os.walk()` from approximately 2N to N, where N is
>   the total number of files and directories in the tree. (And because
>   directory trees are usually wider than they are deep, it's often much
>   better than this.)
>
> In practice, removing all those extra system calls makes `os.walk()`
>   **about 8-9 times as fast on Windows**, and **about 2-3 times as fast on
>   POSIX systems**. So we're not talking about micro-optimizations. See
>   more benchmarks here.

Comment: (1) you could use [`scandir` library](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) on earlier Python versions (2) [don't expect performance improvement on POSIX systems (compared to `os.fwalk()`)](http://bugs.python.org/issue22524). Measure it.

Answer (score 6):

A method to optimize it in python2.7, use `scandir.walk()` instead of `os.walk()`, the parameters are exactly the same.

```
import scandir
directory = "/tmp"
res = scandir.walk(directory)
for item in res:
    print item
```

PS: Just as @recoup mentioned in comment, `scandir` needs to be installed before usage in python2.7.

Comment: [scandir needs installing via PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir) in 2.7, it's only in the standard library from Python 3.5. See the proposal and how it works at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/

Comment: yes, thanks for reminder, scandir needs to install with pip install scandir before import.

Answer (score 4):

`os.walk` is currently quite slow because it first lists the directory and then does a `stat` on each entry to see if it is a directory or a file.

An improvement is proposed in PEP 471 and should be coming soon in Python 3.5.  In the meantime you could use the scandir package to get the same benefits in Python 2.7